# How do I get from Ã‰phÃ©mÃ¨re to Éphémère in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding

I've tried all kinds of combinations of encode/decode with options 'surrogatepass' and 'surrogateescape' to no avail. I'm not sure what format this is in (it might even be a bug in Autoit), but I know for a fact the information is in there because at least one online utf decoder got it right. On the online converter website, I specified the file as utf8 and the output as utf16, and the output was as expected.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is called [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), and your specific case occurs if you have a text stream that was encoded with [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), and you decode it with [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) (which is a superset of [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)).

So, as you have already [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44537286/4747193), you have to decode this file with UTF-8, rather than with the default encoding of Python (which appears to be Windows-1252 in your case).

---

Let's see why these specific garbled characters appear in your example, namely:

- Ã‰ at the place of É
- Ã© at the place of é
- Ã¨ at the place of è

The following table summarises what's going on:

[image: Code table]

All of É, é, and è are non-ASCII characters, and they are encoded with UTF-8 to 2-byte long codes.

For example, the UTF-8 code for É is:

```
11000011 10001001
```

On the other hand, Windows-1252 is an 8-bit encoding, that is, it encodes every character of its character set to 8 bits, i.e. one byte.

So, if you now decode the bit sequence `11000011 10001001` with Windows-1252, then Windows-1252 interprets this as two 1-byte codes, each representing a separate character, rather than a 2-byte code representing a single character:

- The first byte `11000011` (`C3` in hexadecimal) happens to be the Windows-1252 code of the character **Ã** (Unicode code point U+00C3).
- The second byte `10001001` (`89` in hexadecimal) happens to be the Windows-1252 code of the character **‰** (Unicode code point U+2030).

You can look up these mappings [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set).

So, that's why your decoding renders Ã‰ instead of É. Idem for the other non-ASCII characters é and è.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was during the file reading. I solved it by specifying encoding='utf-8' in the options for open().

```
open(filePath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```